# Tailwind not working properly in a monorepo architecture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, darkmode

I am using a monorepo architecture using yarn workspaces, in which Tailwind CSS is at the root of the project. In one of the workspaces I am using React and I have added Tailwind utilities into its styles. Tailwind is working fine in the project yet

1. Whenever I define new colors it is not working.
2. Moreover I also want to implement darkMode to which in `tailwind.config.js` i have added `darkMode: 'class'` and have made a context wrapper to set class='dark' to html root, on changing the theme `<html class='dark'` is set yet `dark:bg-black` is not working.

My folder structure

```
Project
 |    
 +-- packages
 |  |  
 |  \-- react-project-1
 |  |   |
 |  |   +--app.js
 |  |   +--app.css
 |  |  
 |  \-- react-project-2
 |    
 +-- tailwind.config.js
```

My tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './packages/react-project-1/src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './packages/react-project-2/src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  darkMode: 'class', 
  theme: {
    colors: {
      orange: '#E05507',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have moved the `tailwind.config.js` and `postcss.config.js` file inside the react app instead of keeping it at root and restarted the server. Then both darkMode and colors issue was resolved

Answer (score 2):

Adding the colors object directly under `theme` will replace the default color set with the colors you specify. If you want to add colors to the set or override single default colors, you should put them in a `theme: { extend: { colors: { ... } } }` section. This may also fix your dark mode issue.

```json
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        orange: '#E05507',
      },
    },
  },
```

See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#adding-additional-colors

Also, are using an older version of Tailwind? The latest, v3, no longer needs `mode: 'jit'` and uses `content:` instead of `purge:` (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/upgrade-guide#configure-content-sources).

Comment: tried using this also, but this is also not working.

Comment: Did you also remove the `colors` object that was directly under `theme`?

Comment: I added a version question to my answer above.

Comment: I am using tailwind v2 . Yes have removed the older way of using colors and used this also, but not working . For the same issue , darkMode is not working or any other issue ?